# c# serialport question

Tags: c#

i have a USB phone attached to my computer

how do i detect with the serialport which COM its on?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937585/how-to-open-a-serial-port-by-friendly-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over all COM ports and try to get an ident from each one. Below is a minimal example which should be expanded upon for better error checking etc.

```
string[] sPorts = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
foreach(string port in sPorts)
{
   var serialPort = new SerialPort();
   serialPort.PortName =  port;
   serialPort.Open();
   serialPort.WriteLine("ATI"); // this will ask the port to issue an ident string which you can match against
   var message = Console.ReadLine(); // read the response
}
```

You might be able to use WMI with Win32_SerialPort and Win32_PnPEntity as well. I haven't tried it to see what information it gives back.

Comment: mikael thank you very much for this. can you please tell me plainly how would i use this?

Comment: perhaps you might be able to assist with this as wel http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033240/c-threading-and-getting-com-port-of-attached-phone

Comment: If you run the sample you should in theory get an ID string from the COM port which is assigned to your phone. I can't test it myself as I don't have tethering support on my current phone.

Comment: I also wrote something on your other SO q.

Comment: hey mikael im sorry to bother you gain but could you please incorporate this code into the other code example that you did forme

Comment: What are you doing?? You are writing to a port before you know it is yours! This can launch a nuclear missile.

Comment: @Pavel, Like I said, it's a minimal example. And if it's already open, the .Open() will throw an UnauthorizedAccessException. And feel free to post some insight on this. No missile launched quite yet.