# serialport or USB port?

Tags: c#, usb, sms

i am using this code::

[c# serialport question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033324/c-serialport-question/3033402#3033402)

to check what port my USB phone is connected to.

supposedly USB would be a virtual com, but this seems to be incorrect

i used the above code to detect where my phone is and the output is just garbage.

is there a way for me to get c# to speak to my usb port so that i can speak to the gsm phone connected to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtual COM doesn't mean it's supposed to answer to "ATI". ATI is hayes modem command, not supported by every device.

Use code in [How to open a serial port by friendly name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937585/how-to-open-a-serial-port-by-friendly-name)